# iOS singleton with static data

Tags: objective-c, ios, static, singleton

I'm working with game center and wanted to have a singleton class for accessing the GK functionality which I've setup, but I then introduced a couple of methods which needed a delegate. Obviously delegates can't really work properly with a singleton, but I want/need the data loaded in this class to be loaded once and be there all the time.

Is there a nice way that I'm missing of keeping the data there all the time, but having the class instantiated as and when it's needed?

Comment: Why can't delegates work with a singleton?

Comment: Does it need to be instantiated? Can't you use class methods?

Comment: Well I guess delegates could work, my concern is if there are multiple objects using it at a given time, and each one sets a delegate then it'd overwrite the existing delegate that is set unless I add multiple delegates I guess. It doesn't NEED to be instantiated no, I just have some data being retrieved in the init method which I'd rather have there than having to call a separate method prior to calling others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy say "singleton class", and by that I assume you mean that this class only has class methods. That's fine, you can still use it, since class objects are still objects. That said, you will probably need to maintain state. Each delegate call will include some parameter that allows the object to identify the sender.

What I would probably do myself is create a NSMutableDictionary in an "initialize" method, then have objects register themselves before sending delegate methods, and when they register create another mutableDictionary, and save that in the first one with the sending object as the key (or some other unique identifier).

Every delegate call has to include the sender, and with that you can retrieve the dictionary associated with that object.

Comment: By singleton I mean that the object itself is only ever instantiated once. So you have a static method of `sharedManager` which returns an instance of the object, but if the object has previously been instantiated, it simply returns that object. I don't need each delegate object to have its own data within the singleton, but the singleton itself needs to contain data. My concern is with there being multiple delegate objects. I was hoping to simply set a delegate of the singleton rather than passing the delegate with each method call. Perhaps having an array of delegates?

Comment: Virtually of Apple's delegate methods contain the calling object, so this is not something unusual I suggest. You many not need to store state information, but if you do using mutable dictionaries is a great way to do it. You also need to insure thread safety if this shared instance can be shared. Having multiple objects works too.

Comment: Yeah I've got thread safety code in place so it should be fine. I'll work something out. Probably passing in the delegate.